# Add new data points on ggplot that are grouped by factors and again by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, subplot

I have two R-dataframes that were created by reshaping the original dataset. One of the dataframes has values for different "Treatment" for different "Month". Another dataframe has the "means" for each sub category.

```
> head(gatheredDiameterAndTreatmentData)
  Treatment                Month Diameter
1  Aux_Drop Diameter(inches).Sep      2.2
2 Aux_Spray Diameter(inches).Sep      2.5
3      DMSO Diameter(inches).Sep      2.6
4     Water Diameter(inches).Sep      1.7
5  Aux_Drop Diameter(inches).Sep      1.5
6 Aux_Spray Diameter(inches).Sep        3

> head(subMeans)
  Treatment                Month Diameter
1  Aux_Drop Diameter(inches).Dec 3.292857
2 Aux_Spray Diameter(inches).Dec 2.515385
3      DMSO Diameter(inches).Dec 4.145455
4     Water Diameter(inches).Dec 4.383333
5  Aux_Drop Diameter(inches).Mar 4.600000
6 Aux_Spray Diameter(inches).Mar 4.587500
```

**I used code :**

```
gatheredDiameterAndTreatmentData  %>%
  subset(Diameter != "NA") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Treatment), y = Diameter)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Month), na.rm = TRUE, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
```

**to make a plot like this :**
[image]

Now, I also want to add the sub-means for each group. But, my plots (for sub-means of each category) are coming very different when I used this code:

```
gatheredDiameterAndTreatmentData  %>%
  subset(Diameter != "NA") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Treatment), y = Diameter)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Month), na.rm = TRUE, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) + 
  geom_point(data = subMeans, size = 4)
```

[image]

**Wny are the mean values so low? I don't think the scaling is any issue here.**

Additionally, I want to draw a line to connect mean values across different treatment groups for different months ?

I have files (dataframes converted to text file) shared via dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/968nfxd5aisizc5/AACsdybRv-QgigGTmMS_7fc9a?dl=0

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of your data with `dput`?

Comment: I have just attached a text file (converted dataframe using read.table). Hope it helps.

Comment: I have shared the actual data via dropbox:  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/968nfxd5aisizc5/AACsdybRv-QgigGTmMS_7fc9a?dl=0

Comment: I wonder if this is because your use of two different geom_point layers does weird things with the scale. Have you tried joining the two dataframes together and using the gather() command to put all the measurements in a "long" view and just plotting that?

Comment: I tried using this code based on example that used two data sets but with same column headers. I originally had a wide data which was converted into two sets using `gather( ...)`. I am thinking scaling is the issue, but I do not see two `y-axis` values. Plus, all other examples I have read really works with the same exact method/code. Its strange, Why would my come different ?

Comment: I can't access dropbox, but doing this with `iris` looks normal. `irismean <- aggregate(iris[, 1:4], list(Species = iris$Species), mean)` /n
`iris %>% ggplot(aes(x = factor(Species), y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  geom_point(data = irismean, size = 4)`

Comment: I just tried to access the data on nother browser in incognito mode. The data is accessible.

Comment: Maybe something like:

`ggplot(gatheredDiameterAndTreatmentData, aes(aes(x = factor(Treatment), y = Diameter)) +
  geom_point(alpha = .4) +
  geom_point(data = gatheredDiameterAndTreatmentData , size = 4)`

Comment: It's working on iris data. Totally. But I can't seem to find the deal with my data set.

Comment: I am thinking, if it has to do with my data (x axis) being categorical ??

Comment: Does anyone have any idea on why is this happening ??

Comment: The only problem with my data was that the "Diameter" values were as character for `subMeans`. I thought that ggplot would handle that well, but didn't and converted `subMeans - Diameter` as factored integer. While the the "Diameter" for the `gathered...` was also "character" it didn't matter. So, it mattered for the data that was added later.

Comment: I converted `subMeans$Diameter` to `as.double(...)` and it worked fine. Such a petty problem that wasted my hours.